# Регулярка PHP как ответ для js

Tags: php, javascript

Дело обстоит так, делаю форму, хочу что бы и на стороне сервера и на стороне клиента проверлялась форма по регулярке.
 На стороне Клиента работает.
А вот и на стороне сервера шлю зарос

```
    $('#Sing').click(function () {
        $('#BoxReg').modal('show');

        var isname = $('#inputregName').val();
        console.log(isname);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'reg.php',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data: {name:isname},
            success: (function (data) {
                if (data.uname){
                    $('#inputregName').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
                    error = 2;
                }
            })
        });

    });
```

вот эта вот часть **var isname = $('#inputregName').val();
            console.log(isname);** ПУСТОТУ ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ И ВСЕ ТУТ ЧТО ЗА НАФИГ?

Код PHP ожидаю ответ вот таким скриптом а там **undefined** что не так?

```
$name='';
$name = isset($_POST['name'])htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']))):'';

$response=[];

 if( (preg_match_all('/^[\wа-яёії]{1,}\s[\wа-яёії]{1,}\s[\wа-яёії]
 {1,}/i', $name,$response['uname']))==true )
 {$response['uname']=true;}
 else{$response['uname']=false;}

json_encode($response);
```

Comment: пробовали вывести результат - `print json_encode($response)` ?

Comment: точно!!! блин забыл echo сделать  СПАСИБО!!!!

Comment: так, но это не помогает(( опять undefined

Comment: уберите `$name=''`, потом попробуйте, как дано в ответе ниже

Comment: меня смущает регулярка можете проверить?

Comment: Что вы проверяете регуляркой?

Comment: строку типа 'asd asd asd'  вроде работает? Проблема в передаче данных от js. А в чем не пойму.

Comment: Код формы выложи

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте здесь поправить код, добавить (`?`):

```
$name = isset($_POST['name'])?htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']))):'';
```

Не поможет, проверьте, приходит ли в массив `$_POST` хоть что-то: `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте заголовок:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

А на клиенте:

```
...success: (function (data) {
     var json = JSON.parse(data);
     console.log(json.uname);

     if (json.uname) {
       $('#inputregName').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
       error = 2;
     }
})
```

Comment: шлет фальш в любом случае.

Comment: проверяйте, что у вас уходит на сервер, смотрите консоль

Comment: Зачем заголовок

Comment: @Amandi делаю вот так в консле по этому поводу пусто  var isname = $('#inputregName').val();
        console.log(isname);
тут нужно по событию что ди делать или как?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман, а у вас обработчика нет? На кнопку повесьте событие `onclick`, укажите функцию и оберните ей код, который указан в вопросе, например, `onclick='ajax()'`

Comment: @Alex78191, чтобы браузер понимал, что ждать от сервера

Comment: @Amandi ему без разницы

Comment: @Alex78191, есть такое, но я привык так )

Comment: Дело в том что у меня модальное окно, по событию onclick  отправляется форма, хотел сделать подсказку при вводе полей, чтоб человек изменил что неправильно и Предеупреждение ушло. НО на данный момент, шлется пусто var isname = $('#inputregName').val();
            console.log(isname);

Comment: похоже что когда я обращаюсь к идентификаторо за значением Идентификатор еще не создан (так как это модальное окно которое должно появится)

Comment: @ДимаПерильман undefined на какой строке? И а какой переменной?

Comment: @Alex78191 на клиенте. Я чуть выше, в редактированном вопросе, описал что у меня выдает консоль.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман И зачем ты код Ajax и код на сервере выкладывал?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман,если я не ошибаюсь, вы шлете запрос тогда, когда открываете модальное окно, а там соответственно пустое поле.

Comment: @Amandi получается да а как тогда нужно поступить??

Comment: @ДимаПерильман, создайте в модальном окне кнопку, и при нажатии отправляйте данные на сервер и проверяйте на пустоту

Comment: @Amandi я это сделал, хотел добавить механизм что бы изменять можно было в процессе без дополнительного нажатия на кнпопку отправить.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман, повесьте обработчик на поле `onkeydown='твоя функция()'`

Comment: @Amandi ок попробую